# Throw GameObject diferences C# & JavaScript at Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm developing a Unity game using C#. I need to throw an object from the main camera. Trying to do it with Javascript seems to work, but I need to do it with C#, and simulating the same script behavior it does not work. These are the codes I'm using for it:

Javascript (does work)

```
var vel : int = 2;      
var objeto : Transform;

function Start () {
}

function Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("mouse 1")){
        var generar = Instantiate (objeto, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
        generar.GetComponent.<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * 2000 * vel);
    }
}
```

C# (it creates de object, but don't apply the force)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LanzarCX : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform objeto;
    public int vel= 2;

    void Start () {
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("mouse 1")){
            GameObject generar = Instantiate (objeto, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            generar.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.forward * 2000 * vel);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using 2 as vel value and the same prefab in both cases. What do I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Can't see your initialization of your variable vel, just make sure vel is greater than 0.

Comment: I agree, vel i C# script seems to be 0

Comment: Hello Chad, I'm using 2 as vel value in both cases, and the same prefab as objeto. Thank you

Comment: Seeing that it's a public variable, make sure you change the value of `vel` in your inspector and not just in the script.

Comment: JD< do NOT USE public variables.  change to private and check again

Comment: JD, simply add some Debug.Log statements and you'll soon know the problem

Comment: Phew, that was a big blast of Unity questions all at once!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check that your RigidBody is active? According to Unity API:
 "Force can be applied only to an active rigidbody. If a GameObject is inactive, AddForce has no effect." Also, in your javascript code you aren't multiplying by vel

Comment: How do I check if is active? I'm trying with this and still doesn't work:
`GameObject generar = Instantiate (objeto, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

   Rigidbody rb = generar.GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();

   if(!rb) this.gameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();

   rb.isKinematic = false;

   rb.detectCollisions = true;

   rb.AddForce(transform.forward * 2000 * vel); `

The problem of vel from javascript is my fault, I copied while trying to delete it. I will edit the post to fix it. Thanks

Comment: By the way, is it possible to use a good code format at comments here at stack overflow? I'm a new here and still don't now how to use it

Comment: it's not possible, no.  only inline

Comment: to check if it is Active just LOOK AT IT IN THE INSPECTOR, it's that simple

Comment: You can check it using with the member 'activeHierarchy' of GameObject. http://docs.unity3d.com/462/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html.
. You can activate the GameObject programatically using the method GameObject.SetActive(true).

Comment: Looking at inspector RigidBody is active, in fact the object appears and falls to the floor, but the force isn't being applied. Debuging it I have seen that after executing this line `GameObject generar = Instantiate (objeto, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;` at the next generar variable is null (but the object as I said was created). I tried to instantiate it as RigidBody and not as GameObject but it occurs the same. How can it be possible? Shouldn't I use Instantiate() method?

Comment: That's because you're instantiating the object "objeto" and it is a Transform. You can't cast a Transform object as a GameObject. This [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/718441/instantiate-gameobject-returns-null.html) might help you

Comment: Thank you @RobertoDeLaParra casting "objeto" as a Transform solved the problem.